# javascript window.open from php script

Tags: javascript, php

I have link which will open new page by ID, now I would like it to open in new window (not tab) and it wont work can you help?

```
<?php echo "<a href='ureditev_v_formo_test.php?ID=" . $row1['ID'] . "' onclick='javascript:window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=200,height=500')return false;'>" . $row1['ImePriimek'] . "</a>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
echo "<a href='ureditev_v_formo_test.php?ID='".$row1['ID']."' onclick=\"javascript:window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=200,height=500');return false;\">" . $row1['ImePriimek'] . "</a>";
```

Comment: This works it open new window, but full size  how to make it smaller like in the code with width and height?

Comment: It works, but I have noticed just now that in new window doesn't open data anymore, I have this for editing person's data and it should open with new window now it doesn't?

Comment: @perofurid check the url, open it new window and then try to debug your script.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open(''+self.location,'mywin','left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0');
```

hope this help you